# Problems with apt-get update and f.lux on ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates, f.lux

[Errors I get when I try to apt-get update without sudo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keHaT.png)

So basically I don't know if the apt-get update is a problem or not. Doesn't cause any damage but is kinda annoying and want to try and resolve it.

[F.lux on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5ZBr.png)

This is how F.lux looks on windows, any way to get it like that on Ubuntu? Or is there something similar. I want to do my own setup on when the screen changes color and so on.

Comment: F.lux on Ubuntu is buggy. Try Redshift (`sudo apt install redshift`)

Comment: redshift is the more comprehensive alternative. For something simpler there's a night mode option in settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should really have asked (2) questions, as these are totally unrelated.

First answer - you *must* run `apt-get update` as root, so the proper command is:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Second answer - here's a link to the F.lux PPA: https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/ubuntu/flux

Comment: Thanks, but these are relatively 2 short questions, didn't want to spam by separating them.